# Compare adjacent column of a dataframe where arraysize is not equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df =pd.DataFrame({

'ID1': \['1', '2', '2', '3','4','4', '5', '6', '6', '6', '7'\],

'ID2':\['a', 'a','b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a','a', 'b','c','a'\],

'AMT1':\['1',2', '3', '4', '5','6', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan\],

'AMT 2': \['1', '3', '3', '4', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3','4', '5'\],

'SAL1':\['100','200','300','400, '500', '600', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan\],

'SAL_2': \['100', '200', '300', '400', '600', '500, 100, 200, 300, 400', '500'\],

'NAME 3': \['A1', 'A2', 'A3, A4, A5, A6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan\],

'NAME_4': \['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A7, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan\],

EMAIL 3': \['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan\],

' EMAIL 4': \['E1', 'E3', 'E3', 'E4', 'E7', 'E8', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan

})
```

Above dataframe I'm using I wanted to compare

Adjacent column for every other column  and set Status accordingly.

1. If every adjacent pair of column match then Status should be PASS
2. If any adjacent pair of column is not matching then Status should be fail
3. If atleast one of them is blank or null then also Fail

Approach 1:

```
Cond1= np.all(df.filter(like="\_\*1").tonumpy()== df.filter(like="2").to\_\*numpy(), axis=1)

Cond2= np.all(df.filter(like="*3").to*numpy()== df.filter(like="2").to_numpy(), axis=1)

df\["Status"\] = np.where(cond1 & cond2, "Pass","Fail")
```

After using approach 1 m getting error axis 1 is out of bound for array of dimension 0

Approach 2:

```
df\["Status"\] = df.iloc\[:,2:\].apply(lambda x: 'Pass' if x\[0\] == x\[1\] else 'Fail' , axis =1)
```

Same error here also I'm getting the dataframe which I'm using is just an small example.

Can anyone please help me where I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. Here's a corrected version:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID1': ['1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', '5', '6', '6', '6', '7'],
    'ID2': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'],
    'AMT1': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'AMT2': ['1', '3', '3', '4', '6', '7', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'SAL1': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'SAL2': ['100', '200', '300', '400', '600', '500', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500'],
    'NAME3': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'NAME4': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A7', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'EMAIL3': ['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'EMAIL4': ['E1', 'E3', 'E3', 'E4', 'E7', 'E8', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})

status_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith(('1', '2', '3', '4'))]
status = np.where(df[status_cols].nunique(axis=1) == 1, "Pass", "Fail")
df["Status"] = np.where(df[status_cols].isnull().any(axis=1), "Fail", status)
```

Here's what I changed:

- Corrected the column names in the DataFrame definition. The column names in your example had spaces and inconsistent spacing.
- Created a list status_cols to store the column names for which you want to compare adjacent columns.
- Used the nunique() method with axis=1 to check if all adjacent columns have the same values. If they do, it returns 1, indicating a "Pass". Otherwise, it returns a value greater than 1, indicating a
  "Fail".
- Added an additional check using isnull().any(axis=1) to see if any of the adjacent columns are null or NaN. If so, the "Status" is set to "Fail".
- Combined the two checks using np.where() to assign the "Status" column accordingly.

Now the code should work correctly and assign the "Pass" or "Fail" status based on the conditions you specified.